# AspectJ compiler (ajc): How to overwrite woven classes within inpath?

Tags: java, ant, aspectj

I have a modular layout of my project sources which are built using `ant`. After having built the project with `javac`, I am running (for a particular module) the [iajc](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/antTasks-iajc.html) task to advise binary classes scattered over the `inpath` that composes binary output directories from my dependency modules:

```
<iajc destDir="${dest.dir}" >
    <inpath refid="modules.binaries.path" />
    <classpath>
        <path refid="module.classpath" />
    </classpath>
    <aspectpath refid="aspects.path" />
</iajc>
```

The problem is that like this the woven output from all the binaries is merged into `${dest.dir}` which means that I am losing my modular structure of binaries as a result. But I need it kept in runtime. Not specifying `destDir` at all has no effect. Is there any way to have the woven classes stay where they are thus overwriting their originals (unwoven) within the `inpath`?
Thanks for any help or hint on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with iterating over elements of the path that composes binary directories of the dependency modules. `inpath` and `destDir` are being set equal to the current path element at each iteration:

```
<for param="path.item" >
   <path refid="modules.binaries.path" />
   <sequential>
      <iajc destDir="@{path.item}" >
      <inpath>
         <pathelement location="@{path.item}" />
      </inpath>
      <classpath>
         <path refid="module.classpath" />
      </classpath>
      <aspectpath refid="aspects.path" />
      </iajc>
   </sequential>
</for>
```

This way classes are being advised in their places by overwriting the original version.